# Mostrar todo conteúdo de um layout no preview do Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Olá,

Gostaria de saber, como(se possível) mostrar todo o conteúdo de um layout no preview do Android Studio.

Segue imagem de exemplo:

[image: Imagem do layout]

A marcação em azul, é um botão que está no layout, porém não consigo manipular ou ver a prévia dele sem ter que compilar o App.

Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui encontrar uma resposta para isso.

Só é preciso adicionar um novo Device em "Your Virtual Device" com um tamanho que desejar (adicionando uma altura que seja do seu gosto/projeto).

Veja mais aqui:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565388/unable-to-see-completed-view-layout-in-android-studio

Answer (score 2):

cara vc deve colocar todo seu layout dentro de um scroll View que é uma barra de rolagem se não os dispositivos pequenos ele n exibira

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"  
 android:layout_height="match_parent"  
 android:orientation="vertical">  

<!-- Todo conteudo -->

 </ScrollView>
```

nesse blog http://requirecode.blogspot.com.br/2016/08/scroll-view-no-android.html vai te ensinar direininho

Comment: Na verdade minha duvida é sobre o android studio, não o layout em si. Veja minha resposta que eu explico melhor. Mas obrigado pela reposta =)